# Unable to connect to cable modem when connected to VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, routing

First I have a cable modem which gives the internet connection. The network is `192.168.0.0/24` and its IP is `192.168.0.1`

Second line, I have a router connected to the cable modem. Its "outside" IP is `192.168.0.12`. This router creates network `192.168.123.0/24` and its IP there is `192.168.123.254`.

My computer is wired to the router with IP `192.168.123.126`.

At this point I am able to access both devices web interfaces by their IPs on a browser (`192.168.123.254` for the router and `192.168.0.1` for the cable modem).

The problem I have is when I connect to a VPN from the computer. Then I am connected to a second network `10.0.0.0/24` and I get IP `10.0.0.200` (along with `192.168.123.126`). I can connect to the router but then I loose connectivity to the cable modem: I cannot acces it through the browser, neither making a ping to it or a tracert.

I have tried to add a new route to the windows routes by typing

```
route ADD 192.168.0.1 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.123.254
```

But I cannot seem to access it this way.

Am I missing something on the route adding? Which is the proper way of doing this?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you using 2 "routers" and not simply using either a switch or making the second router into a switch?

Comment: Your `route` command has an inconsistent network address and mask. If the mask is `255.255.255.0`, the network address would be `192.168.0.0`. Otherwise, you'll get a 'The parameter is incorrect' error. (A network route needs a network address.)

Comment: @MrStatic, it is what I have at home... the cable modem only has one output and I need more than one, so I plug in the router there so I get more outputs. I do not know how to convert router into switch either

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, thanks that worked out! I though I should place there the IP I wanted to reach and not the complete network
Thanks! (I cannot give it as right or solve the question since it is a comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route command has an inconsistent network address and mask. If the mask is `255.255.255.0`, the network address would be `192.168.0.0`. Otherwise, you'll get a 'The parameter is incorrect' error. (A network route needs a network address.)

> thanks that worked out! I though I should place there the IP I wanted to reach and not the complete network

You can do it either way, you just have to be consistent. You've tried to place a *network* route to a *host*.